# C# using ternary operator. When?

Tags: call, increment, ternary-operator, assignment-operator, decrement

Having trouble with using ternary operator.

```
...
char symbol = str_base[i];
int count = 1;
...

(count == 1) ? str_rle += symbol : str_rle += count.ToString() + symbol;
```

Getting such error:
***Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement***

Why? Does ternary operator really only with: calling functions, ++ & -- ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left hand side of your line is a comparison not an assignment (not sure what you are trying to do here). I wish you could use ternary operators for this kind of conditional execution but unfortunately you can't. You can use the ternary operator in this case on the other side of the expression though;

```
str_rle += (count == 1) ? symbol : count.ToString() + symbol;
```

Comment: Isn't ternary operator just a substitution of if-else block? because if-else does work with anything.

Comment: No the ternary operator is in the same class of operators as +, -, * etc it takes a comparison as an operator and returns one of two results depending on the comparisons value. So you have to assign the result to something not run statements conditionally using it.